# Deep copy a class having a self reference pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have a class Employee with pointer variables tag and values of type char and a self reference pointer children. We also have another two integer variables "numAttributes" and "numChildren". "numChildren" specifies how may children can be added to the class. "numAttributes" is for future purpose. I have to allocate and deallocate memory. For this I'm trying to implement a copy constructor and a destructor. The problem I am facing is, I couldn't able to deep copy the whole class when it has the children var not NULL. I have tried using memcpy() and also the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628532/copy-constructor-of-a-class-which-has-self-pointer-to-itself-in-c). But I couldn't able to do it properly. When everything goes well it fails in destructor. What I have tried so far is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public:
    char* tag;
    char* value;
    int numAttributes;
    int numChildren;
    Employee* children;

    Employee(const Employee &attr)
    {
        cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;

        numAttributes = attr.numAttributes;
        numChildren = attr.numChildren;

        tag = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(attr.tag) + 1);
        value = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(attr.value) + 1);
        strcpy(tag, attr.tag);
        strcpy(value, attr.value);

        if (attr.children == NULL)
            children = NULL;
        else
            children = attr.children; // shallow copy happening. Have to do deep copy if it has children
    }

    Employee(){
        cout << " constructor called" << endl;
        tag = NULL;
        value = NULL;
        children = NULL;
        numAttributes = 0;
        numChildren = 0;
    }
    ~Employee(){
        cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
        if (tag != NULL){
            free(tag);
            tag = NULL;
        }
        if (value != NULL){
            free(value);
            value = NULL;
        }
        if (children != NULL){
            free(children);
            children = NULL;
        }
    }

};

Employee createNode(const char* tag, const char* value, unsigned int numAttributes, unsigned int numChildren)
{
    Employee retNode;
    retNode.tag = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(tag) + 1));
    strcpy(retNode.tag, tag);
    retNode.value = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(value) + 1));
    strcpy(retNode.value, value);

    retNode.numAttributes = numAttributes;
    retNode.numChildren = numChildren;
//use this block if we are not initializing the children in the createOffset() method
        /*if (numChildren == 0){
        retNode.children = NULL;
        }
        else{
        retNode.children = (Employee*)malloc(sizeof(Employee)*numChildren);
        }*/

        return retNode;
    }
Employee createOffset()
{
    //Create and tag initial root node
    Employee retNode = createNode("offset", "value", 0, 1);

    retNode.children = (Employee*)malloc(sizeof(Employee)*retNode.numChildren);

    retNode.children[0] = createNode("prnt", "0000", 0, 0);

    return retNode; // Until here it is fine. This return calls the copy constructor first. As it has children the children must also be deep copied. Getting error here. Have to do deep copy the entire the class
}

Employee get(){

    return createOffset();
}

int main(){
    Employee node = get();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly should it do? Since it’s in plural “children” does it contain multiple children? Why isn’t it a c++ container rather than a pointer? And you really shouldn’t use `malloc` with c++.

Comment: We should properly allocate and deallocate the memory. I am not sure why we are not using a container. In my project the code is already written and the task is to fix the memory leaks, the same scenario I have shown here. I have to clear the memory allocated, as a result I have written the destructor, but either an error is raising in destructor or else the initialization is not happening properly.

Comment: Destructors are only called if you, as you say, properly handle memory. That is, use the c++ methods for creating and deleting objects. `malloc` is *not* one of those methods

Comment: Even, if I use the new and delete operators I am facing the same issues

Comment: Then first fix the code to use them and then people can help more. At the moment there’s too much done wrong that it would make sense to try to decipher what’s wrong. Use `std::string`, `std::vector`, `new`, `delete` etc so it actually is c++ and not c with a class thrown in incorrectly.

Comment: To fix memory leaks, use containers...

Comment: "self reference pointer children" I don't think that self reference means what you think it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Employee {
  std::string tag;
  std::string value;
  int numAttributes = 0;
  std::vector<Employee> children;
};
```

no need to write a copy constructor or destructor, the C++ language makes one for you that does the right thing here.

This is known as the rule of 0.

```
Employee createNode(const char* tag, const char* value, unsigned int numAttributes, unsigned int numChildren)
{
  return {tag, value, numAttributes, std::vector<Employee>(numChildren)};
}
```

also a lot shorter.

```
Employee createOffset()
{
  //Create and tag initial root node
  Employee retNode = createNode("offset", "value", 0, 1);

  retNode.children[0] = createNode("prnt", "0000", 0, 0);

  return retNode;
}
```

and done.